# broken code at .push in JS.

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, undefined, push

I cant seem to find why I cannot push my dish to courses[courseName] in the addDishToCourse method.. courseName is an array, so there shouldn't be any issues (although, factually, that't not true ><). Please, help?

```
const menu = {
    _courses : {
      _appetizers : [],
      _mains : [],
      _desserts : []
    },

>>    set appetizers(appetizerIn) {

    },
    get appetizers() {

    },
    set mains(mainIn) {

    },
    get mains() {

    },
    set desserts(dessertIn) {

    },
    get desserts() {

    },
    get courses() {
      return {
        appetizers : this._courses.appetizers,
        mains : this._courses.mains,
        desserts : this._courses.desserts
      }

    },
        //Below is where my code breaks with the .push 

    addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
        let dish = {
        name : dishName,
        price : dishPrice  
      };
      this._courses[courseName].push(dish);

    },
    getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName) {
      const dishes = this._courses[courseName];
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.dishes.length);
      return dishes[randomIndex];
    },

    generateRandomMeal() {
      const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
      const main = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
      const dessert = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts');
      //const totalPrice = appetizers.price + mains.price + desserts.price;

      return `Your appetizer is ${appetizers.name} followed by the main meal, which will be ${mains.name}, and finally you will have ${desserts.name} for dessert.`;// Your bill will be of ${totalPrice}.`;
    }

  };

  menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Caesar Salad', 3.75);
  menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Srimp Cocktail', 6.50);
  menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Escargots Gratines', 4.50);
  menu.addDishToCourse('mains', '16oz Ribeye', 38);
  menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Smoked Salmon', 18);
  menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Grilled Chicken Breast', 19);
  menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Chocolate Lava Cake', 3.50);
  menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Tiramisu', 4);
  menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Kiev Cake', 6.50);

  let meal = menu.generateRandomMeal();
  console.log(meal);
```

Now I tried using an if statement to get around the .push, but that just broke the code elsewhere. Otherwise, I know that I potentially use a setter method, but I'm not too sure on how to deal with that either. Would I set the addDishToCourse?

I am a novice (as seen by the simplistic code^_^) so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `"_something" !== "something"`

Comment: Not related to this issue, but IMHO your `getter` functions should return copies of the arrays, and your `setters` should likewise copy the passed array into the local array.   Otherwise any client of this class that obtains a reference to your internal data can modify it _in place_ and break your object's encapsulation.

Comment: thanks @Alnitak ! I'll definitely be modifying my setters/getters once I'm more comfortable in them. I never thought of that, and it will be useful for the future ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your new instance your `courseName` needs to match the name of the key in your `_courses` object. In your code all of these names are preceded by an underscore so the code breaks.

For example:

```
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Caesar Salad', 3.75);
```

You're passing in "appetizers" as the course name...

```
addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
  let dish = {
    name : dishName,
    price : dishPrice  
  };
  this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
},
```

...and you're trying to add "appetizers" to `_courses`, but `_courses` only has the `_appetizers` key name.

I would change the name of your object keys to `appetizer`, `mains`, and `dessert` respectively.

Comment: Can I somehow not alter the _courses keys and point them to setters/getters with their respective names without the _ and then call on them? 
Also, tried taking away the _ in the key values, and now I have a break in my .legth method heh. so I changed it for 
    dishes.length
but then my code broke in ${appetizers.name} so I changed it to
${menu._courses.appetizers.name}
and now I get the phrase "Your appetizer is ..." but all the values are undefined. 
I'm really sorry if I'm being too needy :( I'm just trying to learn off the books

Comment: Isn't the underscore on the `_courses` object enough? Why do you need them on the key names too?